# Using SUMPRODUCT, INDIRECT and MID to add numbers in brackets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to take the numbers from one cell (X15), from a named range called "Weekdays" (which includes the sheets Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday), extract the number within the square brackets (ex. <2>) and sum the numbers.

I already have a formula that does this for numbers without the square brackets around them, so I probably just need a slight adjustment to get it to do what I want. Here's the formula I'm using for that:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(INDIRECT("'"&Weekdays&"'!"&"X13")))
```

I tried experimenting with `SUM` and `MID` to figure it out myself, putting `<2>` in K16 and `<4>` in L16, and using the formula `{=SUM(MID($K$16:$L$16,2,1)*1)}` worked perfectly. Just getting Excel to use my named range with `INDIRECT` is giving me trouble.

Apologies if that's overly wordy.. I appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Problem here is MID can't be used for 3D references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a 3D Named reference, though you can formulate a 3D reference without using the named range providing the sheets are in a block next to each other meaning that there is no need for INDIRECT:

`=SUM(Monday:Friday!X13)`

However, as `MID()` cannot be used with 3D references ([List of possible formulas here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-a-3-D-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-6a9cc847-547f-40e0-924a-b2ed54cc79a2)) we hit a bit of a problem. Does the solution have to be formulated or could a User Defined Function in VBA be used?

Perhaps you have scope to include a helper column next to `X13` on each page with `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(X13,"<",""),">","")` then sum those instead?

Comment: Thanks for the response.


I'm only using a named range, as on some occasions a sixth or even a seventh day might need to be added. For example we might have Jan. 9 to 13 (Monday to Friday), but we might need to also add Jan 16 (the following Monday).


I like your idea of a helper column, and I tried to implement it. The only issue is that it seems like SUBSTITUTE seems to convert the number to a string? SUMPRODUCT, or even just attempting to use SUM isn't working. Thank you again for the advise.

Comment: No problem, I am happy to help. If substitute converts the number to a string, all you have to do is multiply it by 1 to make it a number again...

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you once again for your help. Much appreciated. :)